Boot iPXE on macbook pro using BSDP
I've recently acquired a second-hand macbook pro from 2013 with a wiped disk, and wish to make it useful.
While I understand the recommendations are to either use the internet Recovery system to install macOS, or connect a Thunderbolt cable and make use of Target Disk Mode in order to install anything else, I still wish to provision an operating system in a cleaner and more reproducible automated way. Surely that should be possible?
On non-apple hardware I typically use iPXE, and this answer tells that to be possible also on any intel-based macbook if booting from removable media. The way I understand things, it also ought to be possible to boot iPXE over the network using Apple's Boot Service Discovery Protocol (BSDP), as accessed by pressing N to launch a NetInstall from a NetBoot server.
It seems all one needs to know, is how to populate the configuration for one's DHCP and tftp servers. The Wikipedia page on BSDP is quite technical. Together with the specification it references, it appears to be detailed enough to allow setting up this two-stage network boot solution which I am after. Yet it seems fiddly enough to motivate asking first; Does this SE community know of any previous attempts to serve iPXE over BSDP? (Related answers about success stories or other implementations than Apple's serving of macOS over BSDP could perhaps also be interesting and on topic?)
One possible problem I see is regarding driver support. While iPXE does have some support for booting over wifi, I'm unsure of if it will work with the device in the macbook. Running ioreg | grep AirPort in the rescue shell reveals a BroadCom 4360. There is support for Broadcom bcm44xx cards in the source tree, but I have no clue of whether those model numbers might be close enough to be similar technology.

I’d head straight to the tool we depended upon for this era of hardware. http://www.deploystudio.com/ what you ask is absolutely possible but the implementation details and timing and coding wasn’t trivial. DS did everything your goals ask for if you’re looking for a practical solution and not intending to re-implement this or use other components for the server side

As hinted in the question, I'm wishing to reuse my existing infrastructure for installing on Apple hardware. The linked page about deploystudio is not very descriptive, but it appears to merely be a closed source disk-imaging solution for macOS and is self-described as legacy. Automated installation of a modern operating system using the dynamics of ipxe scripts is what I desire. The question is about whether one can skip the USB-stick when booting iPXE. I expect the answer to only require configuration, no coding. Question seemed on-topic here, but may it should be on superuser.com?

I think you’ll get excellent answers here. Just didn’t want you to miss a quick win. That tool was epic and still is quality. Was updated all the time and lost steam once MDM and zero touch enrollment became the way large corporations did their rollouts. Other than being sherlocked, it would still be the tool today IMO.

How many net boot images are you thinking of building or hosting for macOS hardware?

Ah! So apart from getting the server config correct, the format of of the fetched file must be .nbi. To my understanding that format is documented in the macOS flavour of bootpd(8), and seems to encapsulate at least one dmg. Good to know, thanks @bmike. One single such .nbi containing iPXE should suffice to allow all further bootstrapping, I hope.

Indeed - hit up the slack if you want to talk to the people that wrote a ton of this code and used it - https://www.macadmins.org/

Now I'm able to answer my own question, after seemingly having gone down one rabbit-hole and come up through another.
As the conversation in the comments on the question goes, it should probably be possible to place iPXE in an Apple Disk Image inside a NetBoot Image and chainload into it using BSDP. However, as always, the devil is in the details and with my specific hardware (MacBookPro11,1; A1502 EMC 2678) this idea is not feasible to pursuit.
The weakest link is the wifi interface, the Broadcom bcm4360 with pci id 14e4:43a0. These cards are not like the bcm44xx series. As a matter of fact, they are not even comparable to other bcm43xx cards. The only datasheet one can ever find for them, at least without signing an NDA, is a thin eight page document describing trivial things such as its physical dimensions. Unlike the similarly named cards, no one has published any open-source drivers. To the best of my understanding the wifi is almost completely unusable with FreeBSD, illumos, NetBSD and OpenBSD. They only work under Linux if loading binary blobs provided by Broadcom (alpine, arch, debian, ubuntu). One can safely assume that iPXE will not implement drivers for a device none of the open-source operating systems support natively.
With no shortage of voices believing facts to be different, the best place to look is the actual source codes. The PCI_DEVID_BCM4360_D11AC constant is not used anywhere in FreeBSD, NetBSD completely lacks the expected PCI_PRODUCT_BROADCOM_BCM4360 constant, and OpenBSD does not mention the PCI_PRODUCT_BROADCOM_BCM4360 constant when enumerating the list of supported devices.
When I was given this computer a fews days back, I believed one could run an open-source Darwin on it. It seems however that OpenDarwin was announced dead in 2006, and PureDarwin lost traction around 2015. Even if there were active communities, Apple would have been contractually prohibited to open-source their wifi-drivers, effectively making wifi-support macOS specific rather available in Darwin¹.
Supposedly there are macbooks with other wifi chipsets. I'll leave my own answer unaccepted, hoping someone will eventually provide an answer which actually gives a full solution to the desired use-case for anyone with a supported card.
